# How to create one page site with multi languages routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm using `Gatsby` and I would like to create a one site using multilanguage, so far I've defined `pages/index.js` which contains this:

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout"

import BGTState from "../context/bgt/bgtState"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Home from "../components/pages/home"
import Collection from "../components/pages/collection"
import NotFound from "../components/pages/404"

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <BGTState>
      <Layout>
        <Router>
          <Home path="/" />
          <Collection path="collection/:id" />
          <NotFound default />
        </Router>
      </Layout>
    </BGTState>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

and I have modified `gatsby-node.js` as:

```
// Implement the Gatsby API onCreatePage. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  if (page.path === "/") {
    page.matchPath = "/*"
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

each request is forwarded on `index.js`, but there is a problem. I'm using the plugin `gatsby-plugin-intl` that add to the url a dynamic prefix like: `http://localhost:3001/en/`

If I visit `http://localhost:3001/en/`, then I get the `NotFound` component displayed because no Route match the url. Is there a way to prefix the url and reroute everything to the correct component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using [client-only](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/) routes/wrapping everything inside the `<Router>`?

I don't know what's the goal in your scenario to change the `gatsby-node.js` with:

```
// Implement the Gatsby API onCreatePage. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  if (page.path === "/") {
    page.matchPath = "/*"
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

If you are not using client-only routes, you can remove them.

It's a broad question but, just define your languages and translation files. In your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-intl`,
    options: {
      // language JSON resource path
      path: `${__dirname}/src/intl`,
      // supported language
      languages: [`en`,`es`],
      // language file path
      defaultLanguage: `en`,
      // option to redirect to `/en` when connecting `/`
      redirect: true,
    },
  },
]
```

The `useIntl` hook will capture the internal requests so, you just need to worry about the views, forgetting the routing:

```
import React from "react"
import { useIntl, Link, FormattedMessage } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"

const IndexPage = () => {
  const intl = useIntl()
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title={intl.formatMessage({ id: "title" })}/>
      <Link to="/page-2/">
       <FormattedMessage id="go_page2" />
      </Link>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default IndexPage
```

Your `Collection` component should be a page, wrapped inside `/page` folder, or a custom collection with a specific id. If that [page is dynamically created](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/part-seven/), you should manage the customizations in your `gatsby-node.js`, and, in that case, it should be a template of collections in that scenario.

To link between pages, I would recommend using [page-queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/page-query/) to get the needed data to create your components. Your page should look like:

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <BGTState>
      <Layout>
        <Link to="/"> // home path
        <Link to="collection/1">
      </Layout>
    </BGTState>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

The 404-page will automatically be handled by Gatsby, redirecting all wrong requests (in development will show a list of pages). Your other routing should be managed using the built-in `<Link>` component (extended from `@reach/router` from React).

To make dynamic the `<Link to="collection/1">` link, you should make a page query, as I said, to get the proper link to build a custom dynamic `<Link>` from your data.

Once you installed the `gatsby-plugin-intl` plugin, all your pages will be prefixed automatically, however, to point to them using `<Link>` or `navigate` you need to get the current language and prefix it:

```
export const YourComponent = props => {
  const { locale } = useIntl(); // here you are getting the current language

  return <Link to={`${locale}/your/path`}>Your Link</Link>;
};
```

Because `useIntl()` is a custom hook provided by the plugin, the value of `locale` will be automatically set as you change the language.

Comment: sorry for late reply, my goal is to create a single page app, I followed this tutorial: `https://aravindballa.com/writings/gatsby-single-page-app/`. So everything is manage by `index.js`, but actually the language prefix in the url is not handled...

Comment: Use the `gatsby-plugin-intl` plugin that I've provided and use anchor links then. That will prefix all pages with the languages provided based on an include/exclude rule. Since you'll only have one page, will work for you.

Comment: I already use `gatsby-plugin-intl` but when I define a link like this: `<Link to={`/categories/${ctg.slug}`}>test</Link>` I have this: `<a href="/categories/archive"><p class="bg-title--l text-white">archivio</p></a>` but should be `<a href="/en/categories/archive"><p class="bg-title--l text-white">archivio</p></a>` so why does the language prefix isn't added?

Comment: I've added an explanation. Basically you need to prefix always all your links using `const { locale } = useIntl()`. Because it's a hook, this value will change as you change the site's language so all your links will keep working.

Comment: It's possible prefix all links automatically?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be a good practice to change ALL the links. In this case, it would be useful for your use-case using a SPA but you'll need to change it manually using this approach. Of course, you can create a function that parses and wraps everything to add the `locale` but you need to develop it.

Comment: ok thanks, could you just show me how would you handle such situation using a function like an helper?